# VBA "Check if folder exists" works only when there is a file in the folder

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I got the original code from www.rondebruin.nl

It is designed to test whether or not a folder already exists in the directory. I modified it to fit my needs and it seemed to work well.

Today, i discovered that it only works properly if the folder being tested for is NOT empty. If it is empty, then it returns false (i.e. the folder does not exist).

I can't figure out why this is.

```
FolderPath = sPfad
If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    FolderPath = FolderPath & "\"
End If

TestStr = ""
On Error Resume Next
TestStr = Dir(FolderPath)
On Error GoTo 0
If TestStr = "" Then
    Test_Folder_Exist_With_Dir = False
    Exit Function
Else
    Test_Folder_Exist_With_Dir = True
    Exit Function
End If
```

I suspect the answer lies in the `TestStr = Dir(FolderPath)` but haven't been able to get to the bottom of it. The MSDN [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) basically explains that `Dir()` always returns something. However the examples give are all such that there is a file present to return.

I basically need to get it so that it recognizes the folder regardless of whether there is something in it or not.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line returns a number greater than 0 if the folder exists, regardless of whether the folder has any files in it

```
len(dir("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Tests\tt", vbDirectory))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this instead:

```
Dim objFSO 
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objFSO.FolderExists(FolderPath)
...
```